# Change home folder background on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: filemanager, social

I'm using Ubuntu 13.10. I want to change the background of my home folder with my own photos ...

How?

In contrast to the Ubuntu 10.04 which have backgrounds and emblems, Ubuntu 13.10 nothing at all.

I want it to look like this for example:

[image: example]

Comment: background of your user desktop ?

Comment: no, i want to costumize my ubuntu like this http://netsains.net/wp-content/uploads/2010/09/dikkdd7z.png
but it's not work on ubuntu 13.10

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible in default Ubuntu file manager anymore, however you can install Caja - fork of Nautilus 2.32. After installation go to edit -> backgrounds

*Run commands in terminal (open by ctrl+alt+t or from Dash)*

**For 64 bit system:**

1. `wget http://repo.mate-desktop.org/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mate-file-manager/libcaja-extension_1.6.1-4.1+raring_amd64.deb`
2. `sudo dpkg -i http://repo.mate-desktop.org/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mate-file-manager/caja_1.6.1-4.1+raring_amd64.deb`

**For 32bit system:**

1. `wget http://repo.mate-desktop.org/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mate-file-manager/libcaja-extension_1.6.1-4.1+raring_i386.deb`
2. `sudo dpkg -i http://repo.mate-desktop.org/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mate-file-manager/caja_1.6.1-4.1+raring_i386.deb`

**To determine if you have 32 or 64 system**

`uname -p`

x86_64 - means 64bit

x32 - means 32bit